# How do we detect if a user has ever visited a particular client

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

In every realm in Keycloak, there is `client` which often represent the application the user is about to access which is represented as `client_id` in the url, such as

`${keycloak_root_url}/auth/realms/${realm_name}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=${client_id}&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}`

How do we detect if a user has ever successfully logged in into a particular client at least once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-the-box and depending on the type of use-case and client flow used you could either:

1. Enable the admin events, in particular the `Event Type : LOGIN` and then query those events for the clientID and *id* of the user;
2. If the client in question is using either `Browser Flow` or `Direct Grant Flow` then you can (under the `Authentication` tab) copy and create your own version of one of the flows accordingly. Then add a sub-flow that forces the user to perform an action only during the first login (*e.g.,* accept the *'Terms and Conditions'*). Afterwards, under `Authentication Flow Overrides` (of the client) override the flow with your customized flow, accordingly. Finally, query the user for the *first login action* required by the client in question.

**DISCLAIMER:** I am not claiming that those are either the best solutions for this use case or that they are *bulletproof*.